Is there any way to put inlined function's definition in a separate place from the declaration?
I am making a small library for my future projects and a lot of functions are so small i believe they have to be inlined. But the problem is that i have too many small inlined functions take too much space in headers. Is there some way to put these functions in other files without any errors? I want my header files to look clean and readable like a list of methods, not a bunch of single line definitions.
Is putting inlined function's definition in the same file but after all declarations a standard practice? Should i do that?
Just putting definition for functions in .cpp files doesn't work, it returns error LNK2019.
Trying to put definitions on other file and include it in header doesn't work either because it creates circular reference.

Put them in another file say .inl and #include this file at the end of the header file.

@user12002570 Compiler cannot inline functions from another source file/library unless you compile everything with Link Time Optimisation

Are you using the term "inline" to mean "inlined in place" (the original meaning of inline), or to mean "weak linkage, with a gentle (and ignorable) suggestion of inlined in place" (the current meaning of inline)?  If the former, you may want to investigate LTO (link time optimization).

@RichardCritten if i do that i'll have to either make circular referance or including declaration file everywhere else which seems wrong to me

Nope: you just need to spit the header file into 2 parts: (1) declarations and (2) implementations.  Move the implementations into the .inl file and #include the .inl file at the end of the original header file.

@Eljay: Be careful about relying on LTO for inlining, instead of organizing code into header files.  LTO kills the performance of minimum rebuild.

@Eljay i just researched(watched a youtube video) what LTO is, and this is exactly what i needed.

You can definitely split a header file into multiple files.  You need to decide whether:
A. The additional files are separate components

Users will include all component headers that they use
The component headers begin by #include-ing the common header
The common header will not #include components

or
B. It's all one component, split as an implementation detail

Users will include the single public header
The detailed headers will NOT include the public header
The public header will #include the detailed headers AFTER common declarations.

Failing to make this decision is likely how you ended up with circular includes.
Making one massive header file with declarations on top and function bodies below is also fine.  That's what the compiler is going to see anyway, after preprocessing.

I don't quite understand what should include what. How can a file with definitions, make the definitions without including file with declarations? Making it so the definitions file is the public one also seems wrong to me

Say, you have a file xx.h for declarations and another xx.impl.h for definitions. xx.h is for public usage, xx.impl.h is included in xx.h after the declarations (i.e. at the end). Hence, if users include xx.h, they get xx.impl.h "for free", they never should include it directly. Due to the order of declaration and include of xx.impl.h in xx.h, the declarations will be above of the definitions.

@СергійГорбаньов: What you must understand is that the preprocessor treats #include as cut+paste files together to create a single combined file sent to the compiler.  The important thing is that in the compiler input, the forward declarations come before the function bodies.  The compiler does not care at all whether the beginning of B.h has #include "A.h" or the end of A.h has #include "B.h".  Both of them result in compiling the contents of A.h followed by the contents of B.h

@Scheff'sCat i've already tried that and for some reason got error "C2653 'MyClass' is not a class or namespace name"

I'm using visual studio so i suppose that might be related to the that i'm not calling compiler or linker manually or something like that

@СергійГорбаньов: Does it work for you as one large header file?  Get that working first, then if you prefer multiple files, you can move a chunk to another file and put a #include in exactly the location where the chunk was working (not at the top).

It does work in one file. But when i move function's definition to another file, and i compile it, it still returns C2653 for some reason

I can only assume that you either (a) did not put the #include in the spot that the function occupied before the move, as I instructed, or (b) moved the function into an existing file that's already included in one or more places.

Whether or not a function is inlined is an implementation detail that you should not care about.
There is nothing wrong with having a header file containing a bazillion small “inline” method definitions. It can still be pretty and easy-to-read and handled well by the compiler. Let the compiler do its job.
The header would need to prototype the function/method definitions either way.

To separate inline definitions from class declaration, put inline definitions in another header including the declarations, and include that header in cpp file :
Math.hpp
#pragma once

class Math {
public :
  Math () {}
  ~Math () {}
  static int add (int a, int b);
};

Math2.hpp : inline definitions
#pragma once
#include "Math.hpp"
inline int Math::add (int a, int b) {
  return a+b;
}

TestMath.cpp
#include "Math2.hpp"
#include <iostream>
int main (int argc, char* argv []) {
  int a (2), b (3);
  std::cout << a << "+" << b << " == " << Math::add (a, b) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}


That just shuffles the problem to another header file.

I think it's not a good practice to have to include file with implementations, instead of declarations. but that still does separate implementations and declaration

@Dúthomhas and that's exactly what i wanted. it just separates inlined function's implementations from their declarations
